# getting the error : Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "of"

Tags: android, runtime-error

i am getting this error :
" Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "of": syntax error: CREATE TABLE List of Notes (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, notes_nameTEXT NOT NULL notes_contentTEXT NOT NULL notes_timeTEXT NOT NULL); "

I am using this code:

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                        KEY_ROWID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        KEY_NAME + "TEXT NOT NULL " + 
                        KEY_CONTENT + "TEXT NOT NULL " +
                        KEY_TIME + "TEXT NOT NULL);"

                        );
```

This is my logcat:

```
  12-17 08:58:15.998: I/Database(515): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "of": syntax error
    12-17 08:58:15.998: E/Database(515): Failure 1 (near "of": syntax error) on 0x22ddf8 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE List of Notes (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, notes_nameTEXT NOT NULL, notes_contentTEXT NOT NULL, notes_timeTEXT NOT NULL);'.
    12-17 08:58:16.060: D/AndroidRuntime(515): Shutting down VM
    12-17 08:58:16.068: W/dalvikvm(515): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.compilationofnotes.pragya/com.compilationofnotes.pragya.NotesView}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "of": syntax error: CREATE TABLE List of Notes (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, notes_nameTEXT NOT NULL, notes_contentTEXT NOT NULL, notes_timeTEXT NOT NULL);
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "of": syntax error: CREATE TABLE List of Notes (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, notes_nameTEXT NOT NULL, notes_contentTEXT NOT NULL, notes_timeTEXT NOT NULL);
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.compilationofnotes.pragya.SqlDatabase$DbHelper.onCreate(SqlDatabase.java:41)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.compilationofnotes.pragya.SqlDatabase.open(SqlDatabase.java:62)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.compilationofnotes.pragya.NotesView.onCreate(NotesView.java:23)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    12-17 08:58:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  ... 11 more
    12-17 08:58:18.848: I/Process(515): Sending signal. PID: 515 SIG: 9
```

This is my new logcat:

```
12-17 09:27:25.535: D/AndroidRuntime(357): Shutting down VM
12-17 09:27:25.535: W/dalvikvm(357): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.compilationofnotes.pragya/com.compilationofnotes.pragya.NewNote}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.compilationofnotes.pragya.NewNote.onCreate(NewNote.java:28)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-17 09:27:25.578: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  ... 11 more
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of the great advice in the other answer.

```
CREATE TABLE List of Notes (
```

A table name must be one word. Consider `ListOfNames`, `List_of_Names`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Sam! The error went! 
BUT now i am getting this error: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: CREATE TABLE ListOfNotes (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, notes_nameTEXT NOT NULL, notes_contentTEXT NOT NULL, notes_timeTEXT NOT NULL);

Comment: @phoenix Look closely at your error, you need to add spaces after all of your column names: `_idINTEGER`.

Comment: Thanks! I myself too spotted the error after commenting here! Sorry for that :P  BUT i am again getting errors. I have updated my logcat in my original question.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.compilationofnotes.pragya.NewNote.onCreate(NewNote.java:28)` Your new error is in `NewNote#onCreate()`, you should post a new question with your `onCreate()` code and that LogCat since this is a different problem from the original SQLite question.

Comment: Error resolved!!!
Yeah. Problem was in the onCreate() 
Thank u so much. Really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Change your create table query as:

```
  String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
            + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
              KEY_NAME  + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_CONTENT + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
            + KEY_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL"
             + ")";

 db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE);
```

you are not putting **","** after each column in create table statement

Comment: @phoenix : this is right syntax as i suggest in my answer can you share full latest log when app is crashing because may be other reason

Comment: @phoenix : see this tutorial for more help http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I spotted the last syntax error, but definitely gave you an upvote for your existing work.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K : thanks! And i have updated my question to include the logcat.

Comment: @phoenix : you are not giving  table name in right way remove spaces from table name also declare  DATABASE_TABLE as `String  DATABASE_TABLE="ListofNotes"` instead of  `String DATABASE_TABLE="List of Notes"`

Comment: Thanks! The error went! BUT now i am getting this error: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: CREATE TABLE ListOfNotes (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, notes_nameTEXT NOT NULL, notes_contentTEXT NOT NULL, notes_timeTEXT NOT NULL);

Comment: @phoenix : where is NewNote.onCreate(NewNote.java:28) in NewNote Activity?

Comment: Error resolved! 
Thanks for your help. :) 
Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

use comma separation in your code

```
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                    KEY_ROWID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_NAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                    KEY_CONTENT + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_TIME + "TEXT NOT NULL);"

                    );
```